# How can I use a replacement rule to replace a backslash?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have tried as many versions of the following function, but none work.

```
StringReplace["\[Backslash]" -> ""] /@ {"105\n7.497910", 
 "110\n8.761210", "110\n9.815710"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {"105\n7.497910", "110\n8.761210", "110\n9.815710"};

StringReplace[#, "\n" -> "n"] &[list] // FullForm
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that (at least I think I did) and it didn't work.  Thanks for restoring my faith in what I think I know.

Comment: Having an "n" on the rhs makes it work.  I'm glad to know how to do it.  Why can't you use an escape backslash to replace the backslash with ""?

Comment: Because "\n" (newline chatacter) is inseparable. You don't need the "n": `StringReplace[#, "\n" -> ""] &[list]` also works